# SQL Query to Update All entries with md5 version of name

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I am working on a SQL query to update all the entries in my database (100+ entries around 120 or so) with the MD5 hash version of the `name` in the field `hash` to save from having to manually convert every name to a MD5 Hash and updating them. I am wondering if I can do this with just a simple query in phpmyadmin.

This is what I have so far.

```
UPDATE * FROM `table`
SET `hash` = MD5(`name`)
```

There is already a column in the database with the name `name` I want to take all the entries from that and place their md5 version into the column `hash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has an MD5 function, so yes you can update all records at once:

```
UPDATE table SET hash = MD5(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax,

```
UPDATE table_name SET hash=MD5(name)
```

Comment: Why did you add the where clause?

Comment: ya i know... will remove that.